# Fastest way To Print a page as it displayed in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, printing

I use ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor, and I have a view page needed to print an specific `div` with current display. There is a lot of css in this page to displayed like this, and I don't know about css, I just want to print a div seen in the page as it's shown, so I use `PrintElement` jQuery plugin  like this:

```
$('a.PrintBtn').click(function () {
 $('div#PrintMe').printElement();
 return false;
});
```

But that return me a page with disordered all elements and fonts and directions, So how can fix it? also I see this overload:

```
$("selector").printElement(
    {
    overrideElementCSS:[
'thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css',
{ href:'thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css',media:'print'}]
    });
```

but what it mean? I don't know about css, is that mean I need to write a new css for print page? how can I do that? is there any other simple way to print this `div` as displayed format?

Comment: I believe you will indeed have to write some seperate CSS to do this. The reason that its all unordered etc is because the CSS isnt being used.

Comment: Can you try to remove the CSS class of the div element (using .removeClass('someClass'), before printElement occurs)?

Comment: @Koste The target `div` have not any css class, also if had what this for? what is the relation between remove any css class and print as displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a print.css CSS file.  You can set the display properties of the items you do not want visible to false.  When you link to the print.css file in your head tag, use the following:

```
<link href="Styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

This tells the browser to only use the CSS when in print mode.  You can get even more fancy by splitting up your CSS into multiple files using the following media options

- media="print" -> only used during print
- media="screen" -> only used when displaying on a screen
- media="all" -> always applied

This is most likely the preferred method as you do not have to rely on the client using Javascript to get a print version of your page/item/object.

Comment: thanks that's really useful, but I can't use `printElement` with this, and steel every thing is disordered, I use `wndow.print()`